# I can't find callback parameter in python lambda handler

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm studying for aws lambda - lex and I found coffee bot sample code with node.js.

```
// --------------- Main handler -----------------------
// --------------- in node.js -----------------------

// Route the incoming request based on intent.
// The JSON body of the request is provided in the event slot.

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
        dispatch(event, (response) => callback(null, response));
    } catch (err) {
        callback(err);
    }
};
```

I want use callback parameter but i can't find it in python

```
// --------------- Main handler -----------------------
// --------------- in python -----------------------

def lambda_handler(event, context):    
    dispatch(event)

# >>> this handler doesn't include callback <<<
```

If you need, compare both about

[python docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html) vs [node.js docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html)

---

Actually I want to get this function (build message to lex)

```
callback(elicitSlot(outputSessionAttributes, intentRequest.currentIntent.name, slots, 'BeverageType', 
                buildMessage('Sorry, but we can only do a mocha or a chai. What kind of beverage would you like?'), 
                buildResponseCard("Menu", "Today's Menu", menuItem)));
```

full sample code is here (https://github.com/awslabs/amz-ai-building-better-bots/blob/master/src/index.js)

anyone can help me?

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: thanks for @Momin and {aUXcoder} to edit, help my question

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using callbacks is a pattern commonly-used in NodeJS for managing asynchronous execution. You don't need it in Python (for this specific use-case).

This snippet in NodeJS...

```
callback(null, response)
```

is equivalent to

```
return response
```

in Python.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness to answer even edit my post cleary.

Comment: Given this example, simply returning a string doesn't work as advertised in python. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-migrate-user.html