# AWS Cognito user migration lambda in python, how to return custom error message

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

During the user migration I want to return "Incorrect username or password." as error message instead of "User does not exist"

Have been searching on google for a while, cannot find out how to replicate the following JS example in this documentation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-migrate-user.html

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var user;

    if ( event.triggerSource == "UserMigration_Authentication" ) {

        // authenticate the user with your existing user directory service
        user = authenticateUser(event.userName, event.request.password);
        if ( user ) {
            event.response.userAttributes = {
                "email": user.emailAddress,
                "email_verified": "true"
            };
            event.response.finalUserStatus = "CONFIRMED";
            event.response.messageAction = "SUPPRESS";
            context.succeed(event);
        }
        else {
            // Return error to Amazon Cognito
            callback("Bad password");
        }
    }
    else if ( event.triggerSource == "UserMigration_ForgotPassword" ) {

        // Lookup the user in your existing user directory service
        user = lookupUser(event.userName);
        if ( user ) {
            event.response.userAttributes = {
                "email": user.emailAddress,
                // required to enable password-reset code to be sent to user
                "email_verified": "true"  
            };
            event.response.messageAction = "SUPPRESS";
            context.succeed(event);
        }
        else {
            // Return error to Amazon Cognito
            callback("Bad password");
        }
    }
    else { 
        // Return error to Amazon Cognito
        callback("Bad triggerSource " + event.triggerSource);
    }
};
```

It uses `callback('message')` in nodejs but I cannot find out how to do that in Python.

Stumbled on to this question

[I can't find callback parameter in python lambda handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751551/i-cant-find-callback-parameter-in-python-lambda-handler)

Tried returning message string, but get "Exception during user migration"

Comment: Did you ever figure this out beyond using the custom UI / throwing exceptions?  I am using node in a similar way to the default example you have and the callback logs the error messages to cloudwatch, but still returns the generic 'exception during user migration'.  I thought maybe I could do context.fail('something'); ... but that just went to the logs, as well.

Comment: Was there any solution to this (for hosted UI)

Comment: No solution for hosted UI.

Comment: @james-lin can you put your code in Python please ?

Comment: @hernan I don't work for that company anymore so I don't have the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try raising a ValueError:

```
raise ValueError("My custom message")
```

For me, this changed the wording of the exception returned to the boto client from

```
An error occurred (UserNotFoundException) when calling the AdminInitiateAuth operation: Exception migrating user in app client aeiouffhfha
```

to the somewhat more useful

```
An error occurred (UserNotFoundException) when calling the AdminInitiateAuth operation: UserMigration failed with error My custom message.
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have also tried raising an exception':

```
raise Exception('Incorrect username or password')
```

This still gives "Exception during user migration" in the hosted UI, but that worked on a custom login UI which respects the error message.

Comment: I just tried this and all I got back from Cognito was `{message: "Exception migrating user in app client 7qk...", __type: "UserNotFoundException"}`. I also tried just returning a string value, with the same result. Did just raising an exception allow you to customize the response from Cognito?

Comment: at long as you do it normal UI (non-hosted) one, then it will show up properly.