# Resolving status callback in AWS codedeploy hook

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-code-deploy

I receive this error while running codedeploy

[image]

This is my appspec.yaml file

```
version: 0.0
Resources:
  - TargetService:
      Type: AWS::ECS::Service
      Properties:
        TaskDefinition: "arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-1:xxx:task-definition/xxxx-def:latest"
        LoadBalancerInfo:
          ContainerName: "yyyyy"
          ContainerPort: 80
# Optional properties
        PlatformVersion: "LATEST"
        NetworkConfiguration:
          AwsvpcConfiguration:
            Subnets: ["subnet-xxx","subnet-yyy"]
            SecurityGroups: ["sg-zzz"]
Hooks:
  - BeforeInstall: "drush-updb"
```

And this is what `drush-updb` does in AWS lambda

```py
def lambda_handler(event,context):
    client = boto3.client('ecs')
    response = client.run_task(
        overrides={
            'containerOverrides': [
            {
                'name': 'AAA-BBB',
                'command': [
                    "ccdd"
                ],
            }
        ]
        }
    )
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': str(response)
    }
```

And lastly below is the IAM to run the code deploy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ecs:DescribeServices",
                "ecs:CreateTaskSet",
                "ecs:UpdateServicePrimaryTaskSet",
                "ecs:DeleteTaskSet",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListeners",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeRules",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyRule",
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "sns:Publish",
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": [
                        "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I do have a status code for the return callback based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751551/i-cant-find-callback-parameter-in-python-lambda-handler) but it doesnt seems to work. So what kind of callback does codedeploy accepts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue. I need to explicitly invoke `codedeploy.putLifecycleEventHookExecutionStatus` after the run_task statement.

So the lambda function looks like this

```
def lambda_handler(event,context):
    client = boto3.client('ecs')
    response = client.run_task(
        overrides={
            'containerOverrides': [
            {
                'name': 'AAA-BBB',
                'command': [
                    "ccdd"
                ],
            }
        ]
        }
    )
    if response:
        status='Succeeded'

    try:
        codedeploy.put_lifecycle_event_hook_execution_status(
            deploymentId=event["DeploymentId"],
            lifecycleEventHookExecutionId=event["LifecycleEventHookExecutionId"],
            status=status
        )
        return True
    except ClientError as e:
        print("Unexpected error: %s" % e)
        return False
```